# Nested Scrollview is unable to scroll its full content inside viewpager with collapsing tollbar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview, android-textinputlayout

I have a NestedScrollview within fragments and activity as parent having  a Collapsing toolbar, with viewpager, the problem is that the nested scrollview doesn't scroll to show the complete UI unless i show an error with textinputlayout,

after getting error with textinput layout the view(button) shows up
the activity layout is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    style="@style/overscroll_remove"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_editext_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_editext_padding"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_collapsing"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/color_00cdb"
           app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/dimen_tab_indicator_height"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_2323"/>

        <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Style for viewpager and scrollivew,
        
        none
        true
        never
        none

This is the layout of my signup screen, inside NestedScrollview which didn't scroll to it's full length,until an error shown with textinputlayout, screenshot is attached for reference & layout is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/overscroll_remove"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fs_lay_container"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_layout_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/d_drawable_rectangel_box">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fs_tl_fName"
            style="@style/textInputLayout"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:tag="@string/s_signup_hint_fName"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_user_icon"
                android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_fName" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fs_tl_lName"
            style="@style/textInputLayout"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:tag="@string/s_signup_hint_lName"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_user_icon"
                android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_lName" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fs_tl_email"
            style="@style/textInputLayout"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:tag="@string/s_signup_hint_email"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_email"
                android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_email" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <cl.countrycodepicker.CountryCodePicker
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/fs_tl_ccp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:defaultNameCode="IN" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/textInputLayout"
                android:id="@+id/fs_tl_countryCode"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    style="@style/edittext"
                    android:id="@+id/fs_ed_countryCode"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_mobile"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:tag="@string/s_signup_hint_countryCode"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/di_drop_down"
                    android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_countryCode"  />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fs_tl_phone"
            style="@style/textInputLayout"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:tag="@string/s_signup_hint_phone"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="@integer/s_phone_length"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_mobile"
                android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_phone" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fs_tl_password"
            style="@style/textInputLayout"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:tag="@string/s_signup_hint_password"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_password"
                android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_password" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fs_tl_cPassword"
            style="@style/textInputLayout"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_password"
                android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_cPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fs_tl_address"
            style="@style/textInputLayout"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:tag="@string/s_signup_hint_address"
                android:id="@+id/fs_ed_address"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_address"
                android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_address" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/fs_tl_promo"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                style="@style/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fs_tv_optional"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                style="@style/edittext"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:id="@+id/fs_ed_promo"
                android:background="@color/color_tranparent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/di_optional"
                android:hint="@string/s_signup_hint_rererral" />
             </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView style="@style/textView"
                android:id="@+id/fs_tv_optional"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_drawable_padding"
     android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/s_signup_optional"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView style="@style/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fs_lay_container"
        android:id="@+id/fs_tv_tCondition"
        android:text="@string/s_signup_tCondition"/>

    <Button style="@style/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_layout_margin"
        android:layout_below="@id/fs_tv_tCondition"
        android:id="@+id/fs_bt_save"
        android:text="@string/s_signup"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

TextInput layout various style is as follows,

```
    <style name="textInputLayout">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="error_appearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_red</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead</item>
</style>

<style name="hint_appearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_374</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead</item>
</style>
```

Editext style is as follows,

```
    <style name="edittext" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/dimen_drawable_padding</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/dimen_editext_padding</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

the layout of signup displays as follows,containing a button which is not shown full at the bottom of screen
[image: There is a button which is not fully shown inside nested scrollview]

Answer (score 0):

You can use MyMeasuredViewPager and use this in place of your view pager

```
    public class MyMeasuredViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public MyMeasuredViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyMeasuredViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec,
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (h > height) {
                height = h;
            }
        }

        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```